# Modify Request Payload with Charles Proxy

Tags: json, post, charles-proxy

I'm sending a post request with a json object in the body of the request. I'd like to change the value of one field in the json object.

For example:

```
{ "json_params" : 
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "fav_foods":{
            "dessert": "icecream",
            "pizza": "cheese"
        } 
    }
}
```

How can I use Charles to change `"fav_foods"` to `"least_fav_foods"`, for example, or `"dessert"` to `"appetizer"`?

I've tried using the Rewrite tool, putting `"fav_foods"` as the match and `"least_fav_foods"` as the replace.

Also tried using `{"json_params": {"fav_foods": {"dessert": "icecream", "pizza": "cheese"}}}` --> `{"json_params": {"least_fav_foods": {"dessert": "icecream", "pizza": "cheese"}}}` but haven't had luck with either format.

I've tested and verified that I am detecting the right request. I can add a header to the request, but can't change anything in the json payload.

Comment: How did you test that you were detecting the right request?

Comment: By adding a header to the request and checking if it was there in the network tab and in Charles.

Answer (score 3):

Well, turns out it's *far* simpler than I was assuming. Charles just does a simple string matching search.

Creating a rewrite rule for type Body with Match Value: "fav_foods" -> Replace Value: "least_fav_foods" did what I wanted.